# (Flash CS5.5) Basic Away3D setup help

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flash-cs5, away3d

I've got Flash CS5.5, and I wanted to fiddle around with some 3D, so I downloaded Away3D from the website, and don't really know how to get it 'working' with CS5.5?

Can I just place the folder with my .fla files? Or do I have to setup a actionscript path of some sort?

Also can someone give me a snippet to verify away3d works, as i've tried the following code:

```
package
{
    import away3d.containers.View3D;
    import away3d.primitives.Sphere;
    import flash.display.Sprite;

    [SWF(width="500", height="400", frameRate="60", backgroundColor="#FFFFFF")]
    public class physicas extends Sprite
    {
        public function physicas()
        {
            // create a viewport
            var View:View3D = new View3D({x:250,y:200});
            addChild(View);

            // create a sphere and put it on the 3D stage
            var sphere:Sphere = new Sphere();
            View.scene.addChild(sphere);

            // render the view
            View.render();
        }
    }
}
```

And I keep getting the output error message:

```
1118: Implicit coercion of a value with static type Object to a possibly unrelated type away3d.containers:Scene3D.
```

What does this mean?

Thanks alot.

Comment: Line 13: `var View:View3D = new View3D({x:250,y:200});'`

Comment: Check which version of Away3D you use. This error might happen if you use Away3DLite instead of Away3D.

Comment: Are you using newest versions that target Flash Player 11? If so, have you done other stuff to update Flash Pro CS5.5 to know how to publish for FP11?

Comment: Why are you naming variable names with caps?

Comment: I believe I have FP 11 initialized for CS5.5 yes, and yeah defo Away3D.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The constructor for the View3D class takes a Scene3D object. Change

```
var View:View3D = new View3D({x:250,y:200});
```

to

```
var scene1:Scene3D = new Scene3D(); 
var View:View3D = new View3D(scene1);
```

You also need to import the Scene3D class.

```
import away3d.containers.Scene3D;
```

You can find the docs [here](http://away3d.com/documentation/).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a short tutorial on the topic of creating a Away3D scene:
http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/creating-games-away3d.html

It's on Flash Builder but the code is he same both for flash and flash-builder the difference is just where you put your imports. If you don't know about that just edit the publish preferences under the actionscript settings.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

We just need to import the class to our fla files using the code

```
import [foldername]/.../[className];
```

...
to make our flash file optimize, import only the class needed.